# Error: failed to find element matching selector when the selector exists while using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

(node:4067) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "#r1-3 > div > h2 > a"

But when I entered `document.querySelector('#r1-3 > div > h2 > a').click()` on the search result pages' inspect element, it went through. So the selector exists.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = "https://duckduckgo.com/"

async function run()
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    
    await page.type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'stackoverflow');

    const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {        
        page.$eval('#r1-3 > div > h2 > a', el => el.click());
        page.waitForNavigation();
    });      

    const [response] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click('#search_button_homepage'),
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        promise3
      ]).catch(e => console.log(e));
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere my Promise concepts went wrong. Got it working using async/await only.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var sleep = require('sleep');

const url = "https://duckduckgo.com/"

async function run()
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768})
    await page.goto(url);    
    await page.$eval('#search_form_input_homepage', el => el.value = 'stackoverflow');    
    await page.click('#search_button_homepage');    
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    sleep.sleep(5);
    await page.$eval('#r1-0 > div > h2 > a', el => el.click());
}

run();
```

Comment: Note that `click()`/`waitForNavigation` as shown here has a race condition. See [the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) for the correct pattern using `Promise.all`. Also, Puppeteer has a native `waitForTimeout` so you don't need to use `sleep()` from a third party. As an aside, if you're just searching DDG, navigating directly to DDG with the query string appended should be much faster and easier to maintain: `https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=your+query`, saving a page load and the potential that selectors might change on the home page.

Comment: Can you show me the code using `await Promise.all` ? because I tried mine and it's not working. I get - (node:996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.

Comment: It's in the link I shared above, "The correct pattern for click and wait for navigation is the following:" `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click('#search_button_homepage')]);`. Once you get it working, I suggest updating your answer so as not to mislead future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that some sites take a long time to load, and the 200 response does not always come, you have to wait for that piece of code when it appears in the response body. Used `await page.waitForSelector`

```js
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    
    const url = "https://duckduckgo.com/"
    
    async function run()
    {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768})
        await page.goto(url);  

        const searchInputHomepage = '#search_form_input_homepage';
        await page.waitForSelector(searchInputHomepage);
  
        await page.$eval(searchInputHomepage, el => el.value = 'stackoverflow');    
        await page.click('#search_button_homepage');    
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000))

        await page.$eval('#r1-0 > div > h2 > a', el => el.click());
    }
    
    
    
    run();
```

You make a `Promise` for 5 seconds, then you continue to follow the instructions, "sleep" is not needed